# Svelte application deployment

Tags: deployment, svelte, lamp

I have more or less finished my site development with Svelte.

I would deploy it to my own VPS, which will be using a typical LAMP setup.

I followed the doc and made the changes in `svelte.config.js`:

```
import adapter from "@sveltejs/adapter-static";
import { vitePreprocess } from "@sveltejs/kit/vite";

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
  ...
  kit: {
    adapter: adapter({
      fallback: '404.html'
    }),
  },
};
```

Then I ran `npm run build`, it seems no error but I found the following files/directories under `build`:

[image: build dir]

I think it is not right because there is no entry file to load all the stuffs...

Am I doing it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change fallback to 'index.html' or the appropriate entry point name depending on your server.

As mentioned in the svelte Docs:

> The fallback page is an HTML page created by SvelteKit from your page template (e.g. app.html) that loads your app and navigates to the correct route.

Comment: Yes. That is correct.